# impl<T: Config> unconstrained type parameter

Tags: types

Struct

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Clone, Encode, Decode, TypeInfo)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug))]
pub struct Post<PostId, AccountId> {
    pub id: PostId,

    pub edited: bool,

    pub owner: AccountId,

    pub content: Vec<u8>,

    pub hidden: bool,

    pub upvotes_count: u32,

    pub downvotes_count: u32,


}
```

Declaring type

```
type AccountIdOf<T> = <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId;
pub type PostOf<T> = Post<PostId, AccountIdOf<T>>;
```

Writing impl gives error:

```
impl<T: Config> PostOf<T> {
    pub fn new(id: PostId, created_by: AccountIdOf<T>, content: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
        Post { id, edited: false, owner: created_by, content, hidden: false, upvotes_count: 0, downvotes_count: 0 }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
impl<T: Config> PostOf<T> {
  |      ^ unconstrained type parameter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write:

```
impl<PostId, AccountId> Post<PostId, AccountId> {
    pub fn new(id: PostId, created_by: AccountId, content: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
        Post { id, edited: false, owner: created_by, content, hidden: false, upvotes_count: 0, downvotes_count: 0 }
    }
}
```

This will fix your compile error.

You tried to implement a type aliases, not sure if this is supported. Nevertheless, there is no need to do this here.